# How to make a soundboard style program that plays video/gifs at a keystroke

Tags: raspbian, python, ruby

I am a teacher and have had a lot of fun learning how to code solutions to the problems I have. This is a fun project idea - I want to be able to insert little videos or gifs into class at a keystroke. I have a PI and monitor on a cart in the front of my room. I am not sure how to get started with a project like this.

On the PI I have a rails server set up to generate random student names already and would like to continue using that also, but I may need to dedicate the pi to this new project.

I have gifs in a folder, how can I map them to play for a while when I hit a key that is mapped to them?

For example, if someone gets an answer:

-right ... D=dunk.gif
-wrong ... F=faceplant.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you host a web page that can load these gifs up for you. You could use javascript to hide / show different gifs that are in your /images directory:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('hi.');
    }
});
```

What I recommend is that you time the gif's so they only play once, since they seem to repeat, also they are different lengths so you want to make the delay a variable. Here is a basic solution:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <style>
       .dunk {
           visibility: hidden;
       }
       .faceplant {
           visibility: hidden;
       } 
       .centered {
           position: fixed;
           top: 50%;
           left: 50%;
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
    </style>
    <script>
       function showElement(name, delay) {
           var element  = document.getElementsByClassName(name)[0];
           element.style.visibility = "visible";
           setTimeout(function(){ element.style.visibility = "hidden"; }, delay);
       }

       document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
           //http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html
           //alert(event.keyCode);
           switch (event.keyCode) {
               case 100:
                   showElement("dunk", 3000);
               break;
               case 102:
                   showElement('faceplant', 3000);
               break;
           }
       });
    </script>
 <body>
    <div class='dunk centered' >
       <img src="images/dunk.gif">
    </div>
    <div class='faceplant centered'>
       <img src="images/faceplant.gif">
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You rock. 
I already have a site running on the screen anyway, Is there a way that they could be unhidden and be centered on the screen no matter how much I have scrolled down?

Comment: No worries! That's what the community is for. I added the centering into the answer above. My wife is a teacher as well and she LOVES this idea :)